# connection android studio to sql server

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server, jdbc

Please I have been trying to connect my android studio to my SQL server,but it's not working. It's giving me error of connection refused.

```
Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "connectivitycheck.gstatic.com": No address associated with hostname    java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.20.37.39 (port 1433): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

I googled the error and from the results found out that the problem could have come from

1. firewall
2. not enabling tcp/ip
3. and using poor IP address.

I have tried to counter all of this but am still getting the error. I don't know what to do because am working on a school project. I have to submit soon. Again when I checked my SQL server log i saw a significant part of the SQL process has been page out.

Comment: CONNECTION REFUSED means that the packet made it to a server, but there was no service listening for packets on the requested port, in this case, port `1433`. Are you sure the SQL Server service is actually running? And that this is the IP address of the host it is running on? Have you changed any default ports?

Comment: thanks mark for the quick reply...my sql server is runing i made sure of that through the sql server configuration manager.the ip address is that of my system but i  change it to the ip address i found on my sql server configuration manager (169.254.224.52 for ip4)and its still giving me the same issuse.plz how do i verify the port..thanks

Comment: An IP address of `169.254.X.X` means the machine was never given an address by the DHCP server, and is not accessible from the LAN.

Comment: I would say check the connection string again and try to connect with SSMS first if SQL connected successfully then need to think why not working in App

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace, and are you trying to connect Android Studio itself to SQL Server, or are you trying to connect and Android application to SQL Server. If the latter, then you should rethink your approach: Android applications really should not connect directly to a database server.

Comment: thanks for the help everyone i have finally fixed the problem...i had to do with the ip address of my server i was using the wrong one...thanks once again....please i will want to know how to use sessions with android that is when a user logins into an app a session is started to store neccessary info about the user